# EFCore 2 Fluent API to build custom mapping rule

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ef-core-2.0

I have a situation where I'm trying to build a domain model that isn't an exact match to the database and I'm having difficulty trying to figure out how to build the mapping rules using EFCore

**Appointment Domain Model**

```
public class Appointment  
{

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserFullName { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public void MyBusinessLogic(){}
}
```

This is the slimmed down version ,but the gist is I don't want a full blown User object as a property in my Appointment model eg:

```
public User User {get;set;} <== trying to avoid adding this to the class
```

I just want the UserId and some minor metadata like a the User's full name.

I've setup a configuration for the EFCore mapping to still build and map the FK realtionship as seen below

```
internal class AppointmentConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Appointment>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Appointment> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(x => x.Title)
            .IsRequired(true)
            .HasMaxLength(AppointmentConst.MaxTitleLength);

        builder.Property(x => x.Description)
           .IsRequired(true)
           .HasMaxLength(AppointmentConst.MaxDescriptionLength);


        builder.HasOne<User>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    }
}
```

So what I would like to figure out is if it's possible to build some sort of mapping rule for the UserFullName property to read it's data from the User table by concatenating the First and Last name columns, but should never write to that table.

Almost like one would do using a tool like Automapper.

Basically, I just want to be able to say to EFCore, when I query for Appointment data, get the value for UserFullName from the User table and concatenate the value from the FirstName and LastName columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't map related entities' properties directly but you can get around the problem of polluting your model by using a private property/field.

```
public class Appointment  
{  
    ...
    private User user;  
    public string UserFullName => $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}";  
    ...  
}
```

```
    builder.HasOne<User>("user")
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

And don't forget to `.Include("user")` when building your query.

Also note that this user is now being tracked by your DbContext and if you modify it it's changes will be saved to the DB on a later `SaveChanges` call.